# Why DataGrid adds empy elements on DataGrid.Items.Add?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

In  WPF i need, then i click button, i`m adding new row with information to DataGrid. But than I hit the buttin, new rows a creating, but its fill emlpty, not with any string. How to fix it? Thanks for advance.

XAML code:

```
<DataGrid Name="ClicksGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="204" Margin="348,20,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Width="40" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ClickType" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Width="120" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Time}" Width="193"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

c# code:

```
// click class 
public class Click
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Type;
        public string Time;

        public Click(string ID, string Type, string Time)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Time = Time;
        }
    }


// by button clicking calling this method:

 private void TableUpdate()
        {
            IDnum++;

            //test strings:
            var cl = new Click("asd", "sdad", "asds");


            ClicksGrid.Items.Add(cl);   
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Click class in this way:

```
    public class Click
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }

        public Click(string ID, string Type, string Time)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Time = Time;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need accessors in class properties